# jquery load pdf file with .load()

Tags: jquery, pdf, load

can we load PDF file with jquery .load

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What's the point?  When I want to show a PDF, I simply redirect to it and it launches in Reader.  I think this is the behavior any user would expect.

Answer (score 1):

You can load it, yes, it's just an http request like any other. But you can't be sure of how it will look / how it will load, because browsers (and their users) configure PDF reading on the web in different ways!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can load it into the page, but you could probably load it in to an iframe. You would use src attribute of the iframe rather than load().